# get last non-blank row of column google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to go to the last non-blank cell in a column.
For a long while, I've been using this code quite happily:

```
ss.getRange('A500').activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
```

but now it crashes saying: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."
Days later I still get the same message!

When I debug, it won't go past the 2nd line above, so I guess that's where the problem is.

I've searched for a solution, but can only find code that relies on no gaps in the column. My column has many blank cells above the last cell with data in it.

Please help.

Comment: Note that errors like that may result from improper use of `getRange` that extend beyond the valid sheet coordinates. Can you reproduce your issue with just one function in your script project, containing the code here? (Also note you need not `activate()` then get the current cell - just skip the intermediate bits.)

Comment: Ah thanks. The bug was in the range. Someone had deleted some blank rows from the sheet, so it only had 496 rows! I've tweaked my code to not to attempt to go beyond the last row with data. But thanks again because the error message was so obscure it would have been ages before I stumbled across the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop should do the job:

```
var data = ss.getRange('A1:A500').getValues();
for(var i = data.length - 1; i>=0; --i){//bottom-up loop
  if(data[i][0] !== '') break;
}
console.log(i+1);//row number of the non-blank row in a column.
```

Comment: Thanks That's neat. Along with @techhowch 's pointer, I've now got some much better code and a lot more understanding of what I'm doing! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
const data = ss.getRange('A:A').getValues();
let ar=data.map(x => x[0]); //turns 2D array to 1D array, so we can use indexOf
const lastRow=ar.indexOf('');
```